# How to groupby date, find the max, and append it to the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, append

- I have a dataframe of COVID data for each country for each day.
- I want to append rows to that dataframe, for every day in the dataframe, with the daily max.

  - This is to help me build a dcc slider with the correct maximum
- This is an example of what I'm trying to do (but it's not working):

```py
today = pd.Timestamp.today()

df = pd.DataFrame([['china',today,1,4,7],
                     ['america',today,2,5,8], 
                     ['china',date.today() - timedelta(days=1),3,6,9], 
                     ['india',date.today() - timedelta(days=2),4,7,10]], 

                     columns=['country','date', 'a','b','c'])

print('-----dataframe BEFORE appending rows with daily max values-----')
print(df)

for i in df['date'].unique():
    print('-----new iteration-----')
    print(i) # correct
    temp = df.loc[df['date'] == i]
    max_a = temp['a'].max()
    max_b = temp['b'].max()
    max_c = temp['c'].max()
    new_df = pd.DataFrame([['daily max',i,max_a,max_b,max_c]], columns=['country','date', 'a','b','c'])
                                 
    print('-----new line to be added to the dataframe-----')
    print(new_df) # correct

    df.append(new_df) # isn't working

    print('-----end of iteration-----')

print(df) # printing the same as the original dataframe :(
```

And this is what it's giving to me:

[image: output]

I've tried adding `, ignore_index=True)` and `, ignore_index=False)` and neither of those worked either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **See the example with real COVID data at the bottom.**
- Accompanying [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/blob/master/data/so_data/2020-09-08%2063800602/63800602.ipynb)
- Using a `for-loop`, in this manner, with `pandas`, is an `anti-pattern`, and is much slower than the built-in vectorized methods.
- This is easier to do with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

  - Use `groupby` to find all the daily maximum values, for all the columns, and then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the result with `df`
- Using groupby is a faster, vectorized approach to solving this problem.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = pd.Timestamp.today()

# note that the 8 and 7 for china and america are swapped for testing
df = pd.DataFrame([['china',today,1,4,8],  
                     ['america',today,2,5,7], 
                     ['china',date.today() - timedelta(days=1),3,6,9], 
                     ['india',date.today() - timedelta(days=2),4,7,10]], 

                     columns=['country','date', 'a','b','c'])

# find the daily max: 1 line of fast code compared to 7 lines of a for-loop
daily_max = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)[['a', 'b', 'c']].max()

# add column with daily_max
daily_max['country'] = 'daily max'

# combine with df
df_updated = pd.concat([df, daily_max]).sort_values(['date', 'country']).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df_updated)

     country                       date  a  b   c
0  daily max 2020-09-06 00:00:00.000000  4  7  10
1      india 2020-09-06 00:00:00.000000  4  7  10
2      china 2020-09-07 00:00:00.000000  3  6   9
3  daily max 2020-09-07 00:00:00.000000  3  6   9
4    america 2020-09-08 14:38:20.382794  2  5   7
5      china 2020-09-08 14:38:20.382794  1  4   8
6  daily max 2020-09-08 14:38:20.382794  2  5   8
```

- An alternate approach, or in addition, is to add a column of Booleans to select for the daily max.
- This would enable individual sliders for max of `a`, `b`, or `c`.
- Similarly, using `groupby`, but also using [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to maintain the same dataframe axis.
- If there is a metric, where the entire day is 0, so no counted values, then the entire column will be `True` for that day, because `0` is the max value.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = pd.Timestamp.today()

# note that the 8 and 7 for china and america are swapped for testing
df = pd.DataFrame([['china',today,1,4,8],  
                     ['america',today,2,5,7], 
                     ['china',date.today() - timedelta(days=1),3,6,9], 
                     ['india',date.today() - timedelta(days=2),4,7,10]], 

                     columns=['country','date', 'a','b','c'])

# add columns using groupby and transform
df[['max_a', 'max_b', 'max_c']] = df.groupby('date')[['a', 'b', 'c']].transform('max') == df[['a', 'b', 'c']]

# display(df)
   country                       date  a  b   c  max_a  max_b  max_c
0    china 2020-09-08 13:14:25.713340  1  4   8  False  False   True
1  america 2020-09-08 13:14:25.713340  2  5   7   True   True  False
2    china 2020-09-07 00:00:00.000000  3  6   9   True   True   True
3    india 2020-09-06 00:00:00.000000  4  7  10   True   True   True
```

### Example with real COVID data

- [All four metrics](https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/full_data.csv) from [Our World Data](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data)

```py
import pandas as pd

# load first 6 columns of data and parse dates
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/master/data/so_data/2020-09-08%2063800602/covid_data.csv', parse_dates=['date'], usecols=range(6))

# remove World from location, because this is the sum for each day and will always be the max
df = df[df.location != 'World']

# get last four columns, because I'm to lazy to type them
cols = df.columns[-4:]

# find the daily max: 1 line of fast code compared to 7 lines of a for-loop
daily_max = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)[cols].max()

# add column with daily_max
daily_max['location'] = 'daily max'

# combine with df
df_updated = pd.concat([df, daily_max]).sort_values(['date', 'location']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### display the tail for 2020-07-04

```py
df_updated[df_updated.date == '2020-07-04'].tail(15)

            date                      location  new_cases  new_deaths  total_cases  total_deaths
28124 2020-07-04                       Ukraine      876.0        27.0      46763.0        1212.0
28125 2020-07-04          United Arab Emirates      672.0         1.0      50141.0         318.0
28126 2020-07-04                United Kingdom      602.0        49.0     286141.0       40581.0
28127 2020-07-04                 United States    54442.0       694.0    2794321.0      129434.0
28128 2020-07-04  United States Virgin Islands       13.0         0.0        111.0           6.0
28129 2020-07-04                       Uruguay        5.0         0.0        952.0          28.0
28130 2020-07-04                    Uzbekistan      301.0         2.0       9500.0          29.0
28131 2020-07-04                       Vatican        0.0         0.0         12.0           0.0
28132 2020-07-04                     Venezuela      264.0         2.0       6537.0          59.0
28133 2020-07-04                       Vietnam        0.0         0.0        355.0           0.0
28134 2020-07-04                Western Sahara       58.0         0.0        519.0           1.0
28135 2020-07-04                         Yemen       19.0        10.0       1240.0         335.0
28136 2020-07-04                        Zambia        0.0         0.0       1632.0          30.0
28137 2020-07-04                      Zimbabwe        8.0         0.0        625.0           7.0
28138 2020-07-04                     daily max    54442.0      1290.0    2794321.0      129434.0
```

#### Example output with both methods

- See that the daily max for 3 metrics occurred in the United States

```py
            date                      location  new_cases  new_deaths  total_cases  total_deaths max new_cases max new_deaths max total_cases max total_deaths
28124 2020-07-04                       Ukraine      876.0        27.0      46763.0        1212.0         False          False           False            False
28125 2020-07-04          United Arab Emirates      672.0         1.0      50141.0         318.0         False          False           False            False
28126 2020-07-04                United Kingdom      602.0        49.0     286141.0       40581.0         False          False           False            False
28127 2020-07-04                 United States    54442.0       694.0    2794321.0      129434.0          True          False            True             True
28128 2020-07-04  United States Virgin Islands       13.0         0.0        111.0           6.0         False          False           False            False
28129 2020-07-04                       Uruguay        5.0         0.0        952.0          28.0         False          False           False            False
28130 2020-07-04                    Uzbekistan      301.0         2.0       9500.0          29.0         False          False           False            False
28131 2020-07-04                       Vatican        0.0         0.0         12.0           0.0         False          False           False            False
28132 2020-07-04                     Venezuela      264.0         2.0       6537.0          59.0         False          False           False            False
28133 2020-07-04                       Vietnam        0.0         0.0        355.0           0.0         False          False           False            False
28134 2020-07-04                Western Sahara       58.0         0.0        519.0           1.0         False          False           False            False
28135 2020-07-04                         Yemen       19.0        10.0       1240.0         335.0         False          False           False            False
28136 2020-07-04                        Zambia        0.0         0.0       1632.0          30.0         False          False           False            False
28137 2020-07-04                      Zimbabwe        8.0         0.0        625.0           7.0         False          False           False            False
28138 2020-07-04                     daily max    54442.0      1290.0    2794321.0      129434.0           NaN            NaN             NaN              NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

In using df.append, you actually have to assign it back to the df itself. In your example, you are calling `df.append(new_df)` but aren't assigning it to the original df, so it is transiently happening, but when you print your df it isn't showing any changes because you haven't changed your original df object. `.append()` is not an inplace method. Try:

```
today = pd.Timestamp.today()

df = pd.DataFrame([['china',today,1,4,7],
                     ['america',today,2,5,8], 
                     ['china',date.today() - timedelta(days=1),3,6,9], 
                     ['india',date.today() - timedelta(days=2),4,7,10]], 

                     columns=['country','date', 'a','b','c'])

print('-----dataframe BEFORE appending rows with daily max values-----')
print(df)

for i in df['date'].unique():
    print('-----new iteration-----')
    print(i) # correct
    temp = df.loc[df['date'] == i]
    max_a = temp['a'].max()
    max_b = temp['b'].max()
    max_c = temp['c'].max()
    new_df = pd.DataFrame([['daily max',i,max_a,max_b,max_c]], columns=['country','date', 'a','b','c'])
                                 
    print('-----new line to be added to the dataframe-----')
    print(new_df) # correct

    df = df.append(new_df) # THIS IS THE CHANGED LINE

    print('-----end of iteration-----')

print(df) # printing the same as the original dataframe :(
```

This outputs:

```
...
-----end of iteration-----
     country                       date  a  b   c
0      china 2020-09-08 15:00:37.074594  1  4   7
1    america 2020-09-08 15:00:37.074594  2  5   8
2      china 2020-09-07 00:00:00.000000  3  6   9
3      india 2020-09-06 00:00:00.000000  4  7  10
0  daily max 2020-09-08 15:00:37.074594  2  5   8
0  daily max 2020-09-07 00:00:00.000000  3  6   9
0  daily max 2020-09-06 00:00:00.000000  4  7  10
```

before you print you'll probably want to do:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

because as you can see the index for each of the new additions is 0.